# Convert a List to List<Iterator<>> in java

Tags: java

I have a `list<something>` which passed to a method but the method expects like `List<Iterator<something>>`.

How could i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem?

Comment: The solution is not to pass the wrong type to the method. If it requires a `List<Iterator<something>>` then that's what you must pass it, no more, and no less.

Comment: Yes but how can i get that done. It seems that no way that i convert the List<something>.

Comment: Don't try to convert. Pass in the correct data, and yes, do improve your question please as it is seems to be unanswerable other than to tell you these little quips as we're doing unless you can tell us a **lot** more.

Comment: Pass `Arrays.asList(list.iterator())`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is like asking

> My client wants apples but I only have oranges. How can I turn my oranges into apples?

If the method requires a list of `Iterator` then give it a list of iterators! Don't give it a list of objects!

If you have this problem, you must be using the method in the wrong way. But you didn't tell me what the method is. So I can't tell you how to use the method in the *correct* way.

But anyway, if you really want to do this, here's how

```
//Assume your list is called "list"
List<Iterator> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object item : list) {
    newList.add((Iterator)item);
}
```

<sub>Note: this might result in `ClassCastException`.</sub>